# How to block user input when sending text with SendInput

Tags: c#, sendinput

I'm using SendInput (in C#, using pinvoke) to send text to another application. How can I block the user input so that any text that the user may type when SendInput is working is added after SendInput has finished sending text instead? Currently if the user is typing as the text is sent to the target application, the final result may be inconsistent.
Thanks.

Comment: What kind of user input? From a console application or a Windows application or a website?

Comment: Some tips on [BlockInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-blockinput). **1)** It requires admin privilege. **2)** Maybe because input signals are processed by the 'message queue' concept(I'm pretty sure), just chaining BlockInput-SendInput-BlockInput is not enough. One possible solution would be making the thread sleep a little: `BlockInput(true); Sleep(500); SendInput(...); Sleep(500); BlockInput(false);` - this would make sure the user's physical input does not interfere the `SendInput`, by giving some time for the messages in the queue to be consumed.

Comment: P.S. Oh, my above comment was based on C++, MSVC. But C# or .NET would not be different since the underlying functions (Win32 API) should be the same.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're looking for BlockInput?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646290(VS.85).aspx

Comment: @Steven: no, as long as you're doing it from the same thread, so you would do BlockInput(true); SendInput calls (however many); BlockInput(false);

As per the MSDN page:

When input is blocked, real physical input from the mouse or keyboard will not affect the input queue's synchronous key state (reported by GetKeyState and GetKeyboardState), nor will it affect the asynchronous key state (reported by GetAsyncKeyState). **However, the thread that is blocking input can affect both of these key states by calling SendInput.** No other thread can do this.

Comment: Sounds like it's not an solution to the OP, but it's interesting.

Comment: @Steven: can you explain why it's not a solution to the OP?  Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: Or perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but it sounds like her use case involves sending text to another process while preventing inadvertent user input. This would mean that she does not have control over the thread that needs to have its input blocked.

Comment: @Steven: AFAIK the functions aren't process-specific, they operate at the session level, so AFAIK it should work fine for OP to just call BlockInput before and after their SendInput calls.

Note that SendInput also talks about checking the existing keyboard state with GetAsyncKeyState, which the OP may also want to do.

Comment: The function does not take any sort of thread or process ID, so it can only operate on the current thread.

Comment: Yes, the point for me is that I want to send text to a target application and prevent the user from typing when the text is being sent to prevent user typed text to alter the text that is entered by using SendInput. I think that probably BlockInput is not the proper solution to it.
What should happen is that the keystrokes the user types when text is sent by SentInput and played back when the automatic text insertion is complete.

Comment: James is right - BlockInput() will block all user input except SendInput() when the call is made in the same thread; that is to say, SendInput() calls in OTHER threads will also be blocked along with any regular user input in OTHER threads or processes of the same session. Please note that BlockInput() requires elevation to work.